How do I get my For Next loop to actually loop
I have a loop, however it only finds the first iteration and doesn't loop onto the next iteration.
I've set up a loop. So far, it opens a worksheet called Names, counts rows containing IMP and EXP and assigns them to a variable. The Names worksheet contains a list. Column A is user initials, column B is user name, and column C contains either IMP or EXP depending on the user.
Then the macro opens a worksheet called Averages and starts the loop.
The loop starts with a For counter equal to the number of IMP rows. The sets a range with counter.
Next it looks at the Names worksheet and finds a row with IMP in it.
If the cell contains data then sets the rownumber.
Next it sets the variable rng cell and sets it to the current IMP row and 2 cells to the left. (User Initial) and continues to set the rng cell to the right and sets it to the current IMP row and 1 cells to the left. (User Name).
So this kind of works, It does loop through 10 times like it should however my issue is that it finds the first IMP row, and enters the User Initial and then Name. But just copies this 10 times instead of looking at the next row with IMP on it, and entering the next user initial and name. So I get 10 rows of one persons initals and name only.
I have a hard time figuring out loops, Would anyone by able to please show me my error? Code below.
Worksheets("Names").Activate

Range("C2").Select
'counts the rows
 IMPRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C:C"), "IMP")
 EXPRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C:C"), "EXP")

Worksheets("Averages").Activate

 
'Start of loop to insert data 
 For counter = 6 To 6 + IMPRows
 Set rng = Worksheets("Averages").Cells(counter, 1)
 
 Set rng2 = Worksheets("Names").Columns("C:C").Find(What:="IMP", MatchCase:=True)
    If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
    rownumber = rng2.Row
    rng.Offset(0, 0) = rng2.Offset(0, -2)
    rng.Offset(0, 1) = rng2.Offset(0, -1)
    Else
    End If
   
'end of loop
 Next counter


First, learn to properly indent your code. It makes it much easier to follow the flow of execution and identify logic errors. Next, don't use an Else clause unless you need something to happen in that Else condition. Finally, learn to use the debugger to set breakpoints, so that you can step through the code as it executes to see exactly what's happening. It helps you evaluate the content of variables and trace the exact flow of execution of the code.

This looks like you're trying to rebuild the built-in FILTER function?

To answer the logic behind your question, you are looping but performing the same search each time. To get later results you need to use .FindNext and specify it should start looking after your last result.

Lookup Using the Find Method

Option Explicit

Sub LookupIMP()

    Const SEARCH_STRING As String = "IMP"

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Names")
    Dim srg As Range:
    Set srg = sws.Range("C2", sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Averages")
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = dws.Range("A6")
    
    Dim scell As Range: Set scell = srg.Find(What:=SEARCH_STRING, _
        After:=srg.Cells(srg.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        MatchCase:=True)
    
    If scell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No occurrence of """ & SEARCH_STRING & """ found!", _
           vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    Dim sFirstAddress As String: sFirstAddress = scell.Address
    
    Do
        dcell.Offset(, 0).Value = scell.Offset(, -2).Value
        dcell.Offset(, 1).Value = scell.Offset(, -1).Value
        Set dcell = dcell.Offset(1)
        Set scell = srg.FindNext(After:=scell)
    Loop While scell.Address <> sFirstAddress

    MsgBox "Looking up """ & SEARCH_STRING & """ finished.", _
        vbInformation
    
End Sub


Thanks VBasic! For some reason this wouldn't quite work right out of the gate. I had errors, but I set wb as the actual name of the excel sheet instead of just "ThisWorkbook", and also Set sws as wb,Worksheets("Names").  Again, unsure why but changing these fixed the error. Thanks for your help. very much appreciated.

An alternative using ADO with a case-sensitive approach is;
Sub Test()
    Dim adoCN As Object, RS As Object
    Dim myFile As String, strSQL As String
    
    myFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    
    Set adoCN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set RS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    
    adoCN.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    adoCN.Properties("Data Source") = myFile
    adoCN.Properties("Extended Properties") = "Excel 12.0 Macro; HDR=Yes; IMEX=1"
    adoCN.Open
    
    strSQL = "Select [Name], [Num] From [Names$] Where StrComp([Crit], 'IMP', 0) = 0"
    RS.Open strSQL, adoCN
    
    Sheets("Averages").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset RS
    
    RS.Close
    
    Set RS = Nothing
    Set adoCN = Nothing
End Sub


Thanks Haluk, Unfortunately this one is too complicated to follow for my limited knowledge.
